# Where does the Panel Mount BNC Connector make the ground connection to my PCB?

Tags: ground, bnc

This may be a dumb question, but where does the PCB make a connection with the signal ground on this BNC connector? All I see is the signal pin that is soldered on (via solder cup) and no where is there the possibility to solder to a reference ground.
The part is Digikey PN A32342-ND

Thanks

[image]

Comment: I recall using a lockwasher/solder lug with those connectors - don't recall if the lug came with the connector or was a separate order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, that's a grounded bulkhead connector. The housing may be connected at many places to the PCB (if any), and probably is if it's an RF circuit.

AMP aka Tyco aka TE [offers](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1307191_BNC_Connectors&DocType=CS&DocLang=English) similar types with and without a toothed washer to add a a wire to the panel.

[image]

Insulated bulkhead connectors have two solder terminals.

Comment: Thanks, I actually find one with a through hole solder ground post I think would be easier -- https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/5227222-3/A32262-ND/811160

Comment: That’s a PCB - mount type and it is insulated from the panel, which may or may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't necessarily do – not all BNC applications are so high in frequency that a gap matters, so maybe, if present at all, the outer conductor (that's not necessarily ground!) is just connected to the chassis somewhere else, or soldered to a brass washer that gets fastened with the nut.